# Makecert.exe hangs

Tags: windows-vista

I was following the steps in [Scott Hanselman's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx) describing how to create a certificate authority and code signing certificate for PowerShell scripts.

Initially, I created the certificate authority and a personal certifcate and used it to sign a powershell script successfully.  All went as described in the blog post.

The problem starts (as most do) when I did something that was (probably) stupid, although it seemed reasonable at the time.

I wanted to start over and repeat the process again with a clean slate, so from the mmc certificates snap-in console, I deleted the personal certificate and the certificate authority I created previously. After that any time I try to use makecert, (just as I did the first time around), makecert either hangs or faults (which prompts to end or debug).

Did I hose something up by deleting via the certificates snap-in?  It didn't complain or warn me that it could be potentially hazardous.  Is this just coincidence and something else entirely could be hosed?

I have Event Log entries from the times when makecert crashed, which all look very similar; here is one:

```
   Log Name:      Application
   Source:        Application Error
   Date:          8/5/2009 3:55:04 PM
   Event ID:      1000
   Task Category: (100)
   Level:         Error
   Description:
   Faulting application makecert.exe, version 6.0.6000.16384, 
   time stamp 0x4545910b, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18005, 
   time stamp 0x49e03821, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00067409, 
   process id 0xe58, application start time 0x01ca160efdf30625.
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what exactly caused this and/or what I can do to fix it.

I'm on 32-bit Vista Enterprise w/SP2.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug. The exception code is 0xc0000005, which means it is an access violation. This should create a dump file on your machine. To dig further into this, load the dump file in windbg and get a stack trace. Then post the stack trace here.